# UNION and LIMIT alone operations in MySQL one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get these results

```
id   details
-----------------
 6   I am old car
 7   I am old car
 8   I am old car
 9   I am old car
10   I am old car
 6   I am New car
 7   I am New car
 8   I am New car
 9   I am New car
10   I am New car
```

I use the MySQL query

```
SELECT Cars.details FROM Cars WHERE Old = 'Old'
LIMIT 5, 5
UNION
SELECT Cars.details FROM Cars WHERE New = 'New'
LIMIT 5, 5
```

But I get the results from the new cars only.

The result starts from 1-5
Is it possible to get the desired result in groups of five, in both of these groups

Is there a possibility to split the query LIMIT but stay in one query?

Comment: Your sample data do not contain `Old` or `New` fields. Can you show us the actual schema of your table?

Comment: A union comes with an implied distinct so I suspect car.details may be the same for both selects. Try changing to union all.

Comment: https://imgur.com/hr9ISke

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ffw2w

Comment: Images not good can you add sample data to the question as text?

Comment: SELECT details FROM Cars WHERE Old = 'Old' LIMIT 5, 5 UNION ALL SELECT details FROM Cars WHERE New = 'New' LIMIT 5, 5

Comment: i am New car 1 i am New car 2 i am New car 3 i am New car 4 i am New car 5

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> drop table if exists Cars;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

mysql> create table Cars (id int , details varchar(20),old varchar(3), new varchar(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> insert into Cars values
    -> ( 6 ,  'I am old car','old', null),
    -> (7  , 'I am old car','old', null),
    ->  (8  , 'I am old car','old', null),
    ->  (9 ,  'I am old car','old', null),
    -> (10  , 'I am old car','old', null),
    -> ( 6 ,  'I am New car',null, 'new'),
    -> ( 7  , 'I am New car',null, 'new'),
    -> (8  , 'I am New car',null, 'new'),
    -> ( 9 ,  'I am New car',null, 'new'),
    -> (10 ,  'I am New car',null, 'new');
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.22 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> select * from
    -> (
    -> SELECT Cars.details FROM Cars WHERE Old = 'Old'
    -> LIMIT 0, 5
    -> ) a
    -> UNION all
    -> (
    -> SELECT Cars.details FROM Cars WHERE New = 'New'
    -> LIMIT 0, 5 
    -> ) 
    -> ;
+--------------+
| details      |
+--------------+
| I am old car |
| I am old car |
| I am old car |
| I am old car |
| I am old car |
| I am New car |
| I am New car |
| I am New car |
| I am New car |
| I am New car |
+--------------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: -> ) a           What it means ?

Comment: any way  
Thank you